# What's the best practice for adding Google Analytics to a project hosted with GitHub pages?

Tags: github, google-analytics, tracking, github-pages

I have a project hosted on GitHub that I would like to add tracking with Google Analytics to. It is a [public repository](https://github.com/maurobringolf/youthinkyouknowjavascript) and the live app is served directly from the master branch. Are there any security (or other) issues with putting the GA tracking snippet directly inside the *index.html* ?

Answer (score 0):

The unique identifier (UA) for your Google Analytics account must be present on a website. You can find them on almost every website by going to "View Source" and looking at the `google_analytics_id` variable. Here's an example from Kickstarter.com:

```
var analytics_vars = {
    google_analytics_id : "UA-7621056-1",
    logged_in : "true",
    social_user: "true"
  }
```

Google recommends embedding this in `</head>` ([source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en))

Comment: I'm aware of that. I was just wondering if there was any pre built solution that I did not find yet. Looks like I will simply include it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: My misunderstanding @MauroBringolf - thanks for clarifying. FWIW, I've always share this value and have never seen any suspicious activity where it's tracked back to my account.